# How to prevent users to see list of tables in Sybase IQ

Tags: sql, permissions, sybase

In Sybase IQ 16.0, when X user doesn't have select access from Y scheme tables, he still can see objects of Y scheme in object explorer in his editor tool. How to make objects names to become hidden in object explorer for users which doesn't have select acces?

Comment: I think it is impossible in Sybase iq

Answer (score 0):

Remove the membership of public group:

```
revoke public from <user>;
```